# Image is not uploaded via django form

Tags: django

**My Views**

```
def apost(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = APostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.slug = slugify(form.title)
            form.save()
            return redirect('apost')
    else:
        form = APostForm()

    template_name = 'dadmin/form.html'
    items = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'title':'Add Post','form':form,'items':items}
    return render (request, template_name, context)
```

**My Form**

```
class APostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {'title','photo','content'}
```

**Models**

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

No Image uploaded is Accepted Photo is selected but when Click save. It shows this field is required error. I had searched through the questions here but request.FILES solves others problems but not mines. Whats wrong?

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in html form tag?

Comment: Umm I missed that. It Worked now. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should use in template where you are uploading form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal form_middle" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST">
#apply logic for media upload
</form>
```

Comment: Good job stealing the answer from the comments.

Comment: Great! Thanks vai

Comment: Thanks @AndreyShipilov your solution worked! I suggest adding it as an answer and asking the OP to change the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

in views.y, the form you are saving should also have request.FILES

```
studentProfileForm = StudentRegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if studentProfileForm.is_valid():
        user = studentProfileForm.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

File upload is a bit weird in model forms in django.
Change your **forms.py** to -

```
class APostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo=forms.FileField(label='Upload image') # or image field
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {'title','content'}
```

*form.save() will automatically save the field.*

Comment: This didn't worked for me.  But <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST"> in template worked. Thanks!